# why this code breaks vc++ compiler

Tags: visual-c++

I've got this snippet:

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
  auto f = []
  {
    auto f = []
    {
      auto f = []
      {
        auto f = []
        {
          auto f = []
          {
            auto f = []
            {
                auto f = []
                {
                    auto f = []
                    {
                    };
                };
            };
          };
        };
      };
    };
  };
}
```

And VC++ compiler that comes with visual studio 2013. To compile this it takes 4 minutes of cpu time plus 350 Mb of ram on average. As if the parser is implemented with some exponential algorithm. Is this a compiler bug?

**Edit**
I've registered a bug report at [connect](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/813710/nested-code-breaks-compiler)

Comment: What is that supposed to do (if not abuse the hell out of your C++ compiler)?

Comment: That sounds like a combinatoric explosion from type inference.  For a worse example, see http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2007/03/28/lambda-expressions-vs-anonymous-methods-part-five.aspx

Comment: @ElliottFrisch: Technically, any source file that crashes a compiler is a bug in said compiler.

Comment: This looks like a situation that would never occur in "normal" programming...  Why would you blame the compiler?

Comment: @SLaks No crash reported in the post; just excess memory and cpu usage.

Comment: @SLaks, running out of memory and crashing is a valid outcome though. Whether or not it's acceptable in this case is besides the point (and outside the scope of this site anyway, OP should try Microsoft Connect).

Comment: Please open a bug on [Microsoft Connect](http://connect.microsoft.com/visualstudio).  This is certainly a bug.  As a workaround, do not nest lambda expressions so deeply.

Comment: @James McNellis Ok, done.

Comment: @SLaks: `Technically, any source file that crashes a compiler is a bug in said compiler.` False. 1.4p2 "If a program contains no violations of the rules in this International Standard, a conforming implementation shall, **within its resource limits**, accept and correctly execute that program." Emphasis mine. So technically, it's not a bug (defined as non-conformance to the standard) but a quality-of-implementation issue.